# SKProductRequest delegate not being called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I know this must be a rather common issue, but I've literally scoured the internet and tried dozens of solutions, of no avail so far... I'm at the end of my wits with this :P

So, I'm implementing InApp purchases on iOS and I've came across the weirdest issue. I did all the setup and early testing of SKProduct retrieval without any fuss, but then the whole thing stopped working and I can't figure out why.

I followed a couple of tutorials, so this code must be familiar. First the InAppPurchaseManager.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

#define kInAppPurchaseManagerProductsFetchedNotification @"kInAppPurchaseManagerProductsFetchedNotification"


@interface InAppPurchaseManager : NSObject <SKProductsRequestDelegate>
{

} 

-(void) requestWalterLevelPackData;


+(SKProduct *) WalterLevelPack;
+(NSArray *) productCatalog;


@property (strong,nonatomic) SKProductsRequest *request;


@end
```

So far nothing too weird. I'm putting the SKProductRequest on a property to retain the value and setting up two "class variables" for outside access to values.

Onward to the InAppPurchaseManager.mm file:

```
#import "InAppPurchaseManager.h"

SKProduct* _walterLevelPack=nil;
NSArray* _productCatalog=nil;

@implementation InAppPurchaseManager

@synthesize request;

+(NSArray *) productCatalog
{
    return _productCatalog;
}

+(SKProduct *) WalterLevelPack
{
    return _walterLevelPack;
}


-(void)requestWalterLevelPackData
{

    NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:@"MR_WALTER_LEVEL_PACK01" ];

    self.request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
    self.request.delegate = self;
    [self.request start];

}


#pragma -
#pragma SKProductsRequestDelegate methods


- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    printf("got an error");
    NSLog(@"request failed: %@,  %@", request, error);

   [request release];

}

-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    printf("delegate called");


    [_productCatalog release];

    _productCatalog = [response.products retain];

    [_walterLevelPack release];

    _walterLevelPack=[[_productCatalog firstObject] retain];

   //_walterLevelPack=[[self.products count] == 1 ? [[self.products firstObject] retain] : nil retain];


        NSLog(@"Product title: %@" , _walterLevelPack.localizedTitle);
        NSLog(@"Product description: %@" , _walterLevelPack.localizedDescription);
        NSLog(@"Product price: %@" , _walterLevelPack.price);
        NSLog(@"Product id: %@" , _walterLevelPack.productIdentifier);


    for (NSString *invalidProductId in response.invalidProductIdentifiers)
    {
        NSLog(@"Invalid product id: %@" , invalidProductId);
    }

    [request release];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kInAppPurchaseManagerProductsFetchedNotification object:self userInfo:nil];


}


- (void)dealloc
{

    request.delegate = nil;
    [request cancel];
    request = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}


@end

SKProduct* StoreItem=nil;
NSArray* productCatalog=nil;


extern "C"
{

    NSString * RequestLevelPackData()
    {

        InAppPurchaseManager* purchaseManager=[[InAppPurchaseManager alloc] init];

        [purchaseManager requestWalterLevelPackData];


        productCatalog=[InAppPurchaseManager productCatalog];


        if(productCatalog==nil)
        {
            printf("empty!");
        }

        StoreItem=[InAppPurchaseManager WalterLevelPack];


        printf("%s", [StoreItem.localizedTitle UTF8String]);
        printf("%s", [StoreItem.localizedDescription UTF8String]);
        // printf("%s", [StoreItem.price UTF8String]);
        printf("%s", [StoreItem.productIdentifier UTF8String]);


        NSString *ProductData=@"Empty";


        return ProductData;
    }
}
```

Here I initialize my "class variables", set up the productsRequest delegate and start the whole thing. On the "Ext C" section I create an instance of the InAppPurchaseManager class and call the "requestWalterLevelPackData()" function. After that I try to access my "class variables" to see if they have values.

The expected behaviour would be:

-NSLog prints and printf's inside the productsRequest delegate to show up on the console
-Class variables would have values.

What I do have is:

-No prints on the console
-Class variables are empty

After some painfull breakpointing and checking I reached the conclusion that the productsRequest delegate method isn't being called. The breakpoints I've placed inside the method are not being reached, nor are the variable values being set. All that happens is a lot of jumping inside the RequestWalterLevelPack() between the actions over self.request and @synthetize.

Now the funky part is that this code actually used to work. I got all the Nlogs inside the productRequest printed out, breakpoints would hit just nicelly and then...no more. The only remarkable changes I did were some name-changing going on back and forth, adding the "class variables" and some testing going around.

Did I brake something without noticing? Can someone help me out?

I'm running Xcode 4.2, target iOS version is 5.0, development device is a iphone 3GS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SKProductsRequest delegate methods are never called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923409/skproductsrequest-delegate-methods-are-never-called)

Answer (score 0):

Store Kit can be tricky to troubleshoot. If you've not changed the code I'd be tempted to consider the environment. Are there issues with the provisioning profile? Are you testing on the device and not simulator? Are you using a test store/sandbox account (and not unintentionally logged in with your proper account.) Now I write this, I do recall a case where I had this "silence" and using a newly created test account was the key to solving it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. That I know of, there are no issues with the provisioning profile, I'm testing on the device and I'm using a test account...Very unsettling...