# Unable to get error description/code for SKProductsRequest

Tags: swift, macos, error-handling, in-app-purchase, macos-sierra

**MAIN QUESTION**:

Why ***func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error)*** is never get called?

**TEMPORARY SOLUTION:**

First of all. I know that I can understand that it fails calculating **response.products.count** and compare to zero. But I want to get exact error code, not just "fail event" with no code and human readable description.

**DESCRIPTION**:

I'm loading purchases list using such come:

```
    let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers:Set(/*init the Set with strings*/))
    self.productsRequest = request
    request.delegate = self
    request.start()
```

Also I've implemented 3 methods of ***SKProductsRequestDelegate***

```
func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
func requestDidFinish(_ request: SKRequest) {
func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
```

The first two are always get called, even if WiFi is turned off.

But the last one is never get called.

For more info: ***SKRequestDelegate***, and its base protocol ***SKRequestDelegate*** declarations

```
public protocol SKProductsRequestDelegate : SKRequestDelegate {


    // Sent immediately before -requestDidFinish:
    @available(OSX 10.7, *)
    public func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse)
}
public protocol SKRequestDelegate : NSObjectProtocol {


    @available(OSX 10.7, *)
    optional public func requestDidFinish(_ request: SKRequest)

    @available(OSX 10.7, *)
    optional public func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error)
}
```

**P. S.**

I've tried to google about it, but I've found only problems like:[SKProductsRequest delegate methods are never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923409/skproductsrequest-delegate-methods-are-never-calleded). But it is not mine.

Comment: What is the response you are getting in the called methods?

Comment: @shallowThought I get SKProductsResponse, it contains products and invalid​Product​Identifiers. I've mentioned that I compare **products.count** to zero, but it doesn't give exact error code.